# GRPCProvider.GetProviderSchema: Error while dialing tcp 127.0.0.1:10000

Tags: terraform, grpc, terraform-provider-azure, grpc-go

While applying terraform plan, we are getting error logs as highlighted in panic output box. It has been working very well on multiple terraform plan, apply and destroy.

And, we are unable to make a meaningful summary of this error. We have even searched in stackoverflow and github issues forums. Yet, none matched what we are facing. They even didn't closely match.

Terraform version: `1.1.8`

Azure Provider Plugin Version: `3.3.0`

```
terraform {
  required providers {
   azurerm = {
    source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    version = "=3.3.0"
  }
 }
 backend "azurerm" {
  resource_group_name = "abcd"
  storage_account_name = "tfstate30303"
  container_name = "tfstate"
  key = "terraform.tfstate"
  access_key = "abcdsample....."
 }
}

provider "azurerm" {
 features {}
 skip_provider_registration = true
}
```

**Error**:

```
Failed to load plugin schemas

Error while loading loading schemas for plugin components: Failed to obtain provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm: Plugin did not respond. The plugin encountered an error, and failed to respond to the plugin. (*GRPCProvider).getProviderSchema call. The plugin logs might contain more details.
```

**TF_LOG= TRACE Error log**

```
[ERROR] plugin (*GRPCProvider).getProviderSchema: error="rpc error: code=Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport:error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10000: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [WARN]: plugin failed to exit gracefully
```

**Note**: Azure region is Central India. Was working fine till yesterday. And, we are working in an air-gapped environment. Hence, plugins are downloaded manually and placed in plugin-dir of code folder.

Please let me know if there is any mistake from my end. I am unable to make a meaning out of this error. never faced this error from terraform.

Comment: A simple machine reboot saved the day after 2-3 days of relentless debugging 

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [**CK5**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5649739/ck5) you get it works by simple rebooting the system. Posting this as solution with RCA why you were getting an error.

**RCA : This is because you might earlier install other plugin for the same terraform file which you might deleted and now you are using with specific version of terraform plugin this might be possibilties to cause error while communicating with azure even though plugin is install.
So make sure to reboot your system and run the VS code editor as adminstiator if getting this kind of error so plugin sync properly to communitcate with azure.**